# Updating PHP Storm leads to a "?" icon

Tags: 16.04, launcher

I installed [PHPStorm 2016.1](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) onto my system via `cd /opt && tar -xzvvf file.tar.gz` Then I ran the `bin/phpstorm.sh` from the command prompt and locked the resulting icon in the launcher.

Then time passed and a new version cam out. I removed the icon, downloaded the new version and repeated the pattern. However, this is the new icon:

[image: PHPStorm Icon]

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

An easier way would be:

1. unlock icon in launcher
2. unpack the new version to whatever location you liked
3. `sh /bin/phpstorm.sh`
4. when asked if you want to use old setting and you so desire point `phpstorm` to the old `.phpstorm` directory
5. go to `Tools` menu on PhpStorm and select `Create Desktop Entry...` from drop down
6. when asked if you want to over write former desktop entry accept and your done.
7. re-lock your icon again

Comment: step #5 is the real key. I didn't know about it. Thank you :)

Comment: This menu doesn't appear with PhpStorm 2019.1. Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Perhaps you should speak a support personnel as I don't think that is normal unless something has changed!

Answer (score 12):

The answer in my case was deleting the `.desktop` file. It was in the global location. I guess I must have launched PHPStorm as root at some point. The command was

```
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop
```

Then I relaunched phpstorm, locked the icon, quit and restarted via launcher.

> $ cat ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=campaign-drive - [~/src/campaign-drive] - UserRepository.php - PhpStorm 2016.2
Icon=jetbrains-phpstorm.png
Exec=/opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/../jre/jre/bin/java -Xbootclasspath/a:/opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/../lib/boot.jar -classpath /opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/../lib/bootstrap.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/../lib/extensions.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/../lib/util.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/../lib/jdom.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/../lib/log4j.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/../lib/trove4j.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/../lib/jna.jar:/opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/../jre/lib/tools.jar -Xms128m -Xmx750m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50 -ea -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd -Djb.vmOptionsFile=/opt/PhpStorm-162.1121.38/bin/phpstorm64.vmoptions -XX:ErrorFile=/home/zippy1981/java_error_in_PHPSTORM_%p.log -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/zippy1981/java_error_in_PHPSTORM.hprof -Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=PhpStorm2016.2 -Didea.platform.prefix=PhpStorm com.intellij.idea.Main
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-phpstorm
OnlyShowIn=Unity;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

Comment: After removed the old .desktop icon, instead of creating shortcut by hand, I run `./phpstorm.sh` script and locked the icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop
```

then check the line for the icon

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PhpStorm
Icon=/home/aubrey/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.png
Exec="/home/aubrey/PhpStorm/bin/phpstorm.sh" %f
Comment=Develop with pleasure!
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-phpstorm
```

edit the file

```
 $sudo nano ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-phpstorm.desktop
```

cd into you phpstorm installation folder then cd in /bin
check the name of the icon
then replace the name of the  icon phpstorm.png with the name of the icon in the /bin of your phpstorm installation folder
done enjoy